# Price prediction works for future year but not for tomorrow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I use facebook Prophet prediction library to model future prices, I can get all the data for the next year, but it's tomorrow's price that gets stuck.

This is the prediction code:

```
m = Prophet(
    seasonality_mode="multiplicative",
    yearly_seasonality=True
)
m.fit(df_crypto_market_chart_exploded)

future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods = 365)

forecast = m.predict(future)
forecast_result_tail = forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail()
#print('\n--- selected: FORECAST RESULT TAIL ---')
#print(forecast_result_tail)
forecast_result_head = forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].head()
print('\n--- selected: FORECAST RESULT HEAD ---')
print(forecast_result_head)

next_day = (datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print('\n--- selected: FORECAST DS TYPE ---')
print(forecast['ds'].dtype)
tomorrow_result = forecast['ds'].dt.date == datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)
print('\n--- selected: TOMORROW RESULTS ---')
print(tomorrow_result.head())
forecast[tomorrow_result]['yhat'].item()
```

**EDIT - ** I modified the code according to the proposed solution but I still get stuck with the numpy error listed below

```
   
       --- selected: FORECAST RESULT HEAD ---
                              ds         yhat  yhat_lower   yhat_upper
       0 2017-06-02 00:00:00.000  2359.464229  605.624033  4037.385324
       1 2017-06-03 00:00:00.000  2371.962255  661.690821  4155.470592
       2 2017-06-04 00:00:00.000  2382.640816  683.686292  4249.680911
       3 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000  2387.433948  570.835239  4240.934785
       4 2017-06-06 23:29:55.701  2226.178108  344.391258  4062.279165
       
       --- selected: FORECAST DS TYPE ---
       datetime64[ns]
       
       --- selected: TOMORROW RESULTS ---
       0    False
       1    False
       2    False
       3    False
       4    False
       Name: ds, dtype: bool
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "d:/Projects/price_prediction.py", line 69, in <module>
           forecast[tomorrow_result]['yhat'].item()
         File "C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 331, in item
           raise ValueError("can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar")
       ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Comment: maybe tomorrow is free day (Sunday, Saturday) and there is no price. You may have to run `for`-loop and check other days - Monday, etc - until you get price. `timedelta(days=1)`, `timedelta(days=2)`, etc.

Comment: @furas , these crypto prices, they're 24/7 - also I did try with days=3 and still same error message

Comment: are you sure you should convert `next_day` to string? Maybe it keeps `ds` as `datetime` and you should compare two `datetime`

Comment: or maybe it keeps date with time (hours, minutes, seconds) and you should get only `.date` from `ds` to correctly compare `==`. like `forecast['ds'].date == next_day.date`

Comment: the dates in the series are in this format ``2021-07-07 00:00:00  34149.989815`` and if I use your code I get this error: ``AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'``

Comment: maybe it needs with `.dt` - like `forecast['ds'].dt.date`. But first you should check if `forecast['ds'].dtype` (or maybe `forecast.dtypes`) to see if it keeps it as `datetime` or as string (and then you should only slice it like `forecast['ds'].str[:10]` to get only string `2021-07-07` from string `2021-07-07  00:00:00  34149.989815`).

Comment: ok I get `FORECAST DS TYPE  datetime64[ns]` and with `forecast[forecast['ds'].str[:10] == next_day]['yhat'].item()` I get this error message ``AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!``

Comment: so it should work with `.dt.date` like `forecast['ds'].dt.date == datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)` without `strftime`. Eventually with `.date` also in `(datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)).date`

Comment: **EDIT:** it may need `.date()` with `()`

Comment: ok I tried `forecast['ds'].dt.date() == datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)` and I got `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`

Comment: maybe `forecast` needs `.date` without `()` - I tested it only with single `datetime` object and it needs `.date()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.dataframe` may keep `ds` as `datetime` objects and it may compare also `hours, minutes, seconds`.

Using `.strftime()` will also not work because probalby it will not compare `datetime` with `string` - but if it could compare them then still it will use `hours, minutes, seconds` for values in `ds`.

You may need to use `.dt.date` for `dataframe` and `.date()` for single `datetime` to compare only dates.

---

Minimal example

```
import datetime
import time

one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

tomorrow_1 = datetime.datetime.today() + one_day
time.sleep(2) # to create values with different seconds
tomorrow_2 = datetime.datetime.today() + one_day

print('tomorrow_1:', tomorrow_1, '| strftime:', tomorrow_1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print('tomorrow_2:', tomorrow_2, '| strftime:', tomorrow_2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

print('           dt == dt            :', tomorrow_1 == tomorrow_2)
print('           dt == dt.strftime() :', tomorrow_1 == tomorrow_2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print('dt.strftime() == dt.strftime() :', tomorrow_1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == tomorrow_2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print('    dt.date() == dt.date()     :', tomorrow_1.date() == tomorrow_2.date())

# ------------------------------------------

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ds': [tomorrow_1, tomorrow_2]
})

print('\n--- dtypes ---')
print(df.dtypes)

print('\n--- selected: dt == dt ---')

selected = df[ df['ds'] == tomorrow_1 ]
print(selected)

print('\n--- selected: dt == dt.strftime() ---')

selected = df[ df['ds'] == tomorrow_1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') ]
print(selected)

print('\n--- selected: dt.strftime() == dt.strftime() ---')

selected = df[ df['ds'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == tomorrow_1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') ]
print(selected)

print('\n--- selected: dt.date() == dt.date() ---')

selected = df[ df['ds'].dt.date == tomorrow_1.date() ]
print(selected)
```

Result:

```
tomorrow_1: 2021-07-11 17:31:50.259787 | strftime: 2021-07-11
tomorrow_2: 2021-07-11 17:31:52.260139 | strftime: 2021-07-11
           dt == dt            : False
           dt == dt.strftime() : False
dt.strftime() == dt.strftime() : True
    dt.date() == dt.date()     : True

--- dtypes ---
ds    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

--- selected: dt == dt ---
                          ds
0 2021-07-11 17:31:50.259787

--- selected: dt == dt.strftime() ---
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ds]
Index: []

--- selected: dt.strftime() == dt.strftime() ---
                          ds
0 2021-07-11 17:31:50.259787
1 2021-07-11 17:31:52.260139

--- selected: dt.date() == dt.date() ---
                          ds
0 2021-07-11 17:31:50.259787
1 2021-07-11 17:31:52.260139
```

---

**EDIT:**

Other example

```
import datetime

one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

today     = datetime.datetime.today()
yesterday = today - one_day
tomorrow  = today + one_day

two_days_later = today + 2*one_day

# --- generate some data ---

import pandas as pd

forecast = pd.DataFrame({
    'ds': [yesterday, today, tomorrow, two_days_later],
    'yhat': [111, 222, 333, 444],
})

print('- forecast -')
print(forecast)

# --- find tomorrow ---

tomorrow = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

mask = ( forecast['ds'].dt.date == tomorrow.date() )
print('- mask -')
print(mask)

selected = forecast[ mask ]

print('- selected -')
print(selected['yhat'].item())
```

Comment: I cleared all the steps except tomorrow's price rendering (I updated the terminal log in the original post)

Comment: see my example - I use `.date()` in `tomorrow_1.date()` but you don't use it so you compare `date == date_time` instead of `date == date`. You need `(datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)).date()`

Comment: I added another example.

Comment: OMG, I was missing the parenthesis around the datetime that threw an error for non-existant date in timedelta...
Thank you so much, now tomorrow's prediction is working!!